# Read Defects metadata in HP QC ALM 12.5x

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

I have to read HP QC ALM Defects metadata using REST API. As per the HP QC ALM API reference below is the URL to read:

```
/qcbin/api/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/{collection name}/$metadata/fields
```

I modified the above as per my requirement

```
/qcbin/api/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/Defects/$metadata/fields
```

I receive below error

[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: What would the end output look like? I'm confused. `$metadata` is it a variable or something?

Comment: @Barney, as per the [HP QC ALM REST API reference document](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/latest/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Fields.htm), it should return metadata of Defect fields. But, it did not work. Anyhow, I found the another URL which would give information about Defect Fields. Will  post as answer. So, would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the below URL which gives information about Defect fields.

```
qcbin/rest/domains/Domain/projects/Project/customization/entities/Defect/fields
```

Thanks!